# Package structure for MVP android project

Tags: java, android, package, mvp

So I have a project where I use MVP architecture. I have trouble deciding how to structure it. My idea is to separate them by feature but where should I put the model classes. So for exemple:

```
feature_name
   activity
   activity_interface
   presenter
   presenter_interface
```

So should I make another package where I put the model that I need for this feature or I put it in here also?

Comment: Package is not problem you should care about code and workflow

Comment: If you're reusing `model class` then you'd put it in separate package, just for sake of simplicity else you can put it in same `feature_package` which will make sense for most of the `use-cases`

Comment: You can read [this](https://medium.com/@rezabigdeli6/mvp-for-android-6784779e35e4) Article, it is about MVP in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample of **LoginActivity** Class :

```
Login
 C   LoginActivity
 I   ILoginView
 C   LoginPresenter
 I   ILoginPresenter
 C   LoginIntertractor
 I   ILoginIntertractor
 C   User
```

In this Package structure

- `LoginActivity` is in connected with `LoginPresenter` by LoginView
- `LoginPresenter` is Mediator between `LoginActivity`and `LoginInteractor`with They're Interfaces
- `LoginIntertractor` is in connected with our model and invoke and fetch to it.
- `User` is our modle.
- We use `LoginPresenter's constructor` and it's interface `ILoginInterface` to define our code in `LoginActivity` and use it.

  You can ignore Interactors.

Comment: So you're saying that I don't need LoginInteractor and its interface? and class User I should put it in the same package as the rest

Comment: Its depend to you. I prefer to use interactor because code is cleaner and debugging is simpler.
our models can be in different package but i prefer use it like this again.
however just start it and develop it and read other sample project mvp on github after a little time you got your personal mvp that's better for you.